# Why do the outputs differ when I run this code using NetBeans 6.8 and Eclipse?

Tags: java, api, serial-port, command, at-command

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do the outputs differ when I run this code using NetBeans 6.8 and Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532845/why-do-the-outputs-differ-when-i-run-this-code-using-netbeans-6-8-and-eclipse)

When I am running the following code using Eclipse and NetBeans 6.8. I want to see the available COM ports on my computer. When running in Eclipse it is returning me all available COM ports, but when running it in NetBeans, it does not seem to find any ports ..

```
public static void test() {
    Enumeration lists=CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

    System.out.println(lists.hasMoreElements());
    while (lists.hasMoreElements()) {
        CommPortIdentifier cn =
          (CommPortIdentifier)lists.nextElement();

        if ((CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL==cn.getPortType())) {
            System.out.println(
              "Name is serail portzzzz " +
              cn.getName()+
              " Owned status " +
              cn.isCurrentlyOwned());

            try {
                SerialPort port1=(SerialPort)cn.open("ComControl",800000);
                port1.setSerialPortParams(
                  9600,
                  SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                  SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                  SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
                System.out.println("Before get stream");
                OutputStream out=port1.getOutputStream();
                InputStream input=port1.getInputStream();
                System.out.println("Before write");
                out.write("AT".getBytes());
                System.out.println("After write");
                int sample=0;
                //while((( sample=input.read())!=-1)){
                System.out.println("Before read");
                //System.out.println(input.read() + "TEsting ");
                //}
                System.out.println("After read");
                System.out.println(
                  "Receive timeout is " +
                  port1.getReceiveTimeout());
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(
              "Name is parallel portzzzz " +
              cn.getName() +
              " Owned status " +
              cn.isCurrentlyOwned() +
              cn.getPortType() +
              "    ");
        }
    }
}
```

Output with Netbeans,

> false

Output using Eclipse,

```
true
Name is serail portzzzz COM1 Owned status false
Before get stream
Before write
After write
Before read
After read
Receive timeout is -1
Name is serail portzzzz COM2 Owned status false
Before get stream
Before write
After write
Before read
After read
Receive timeout is -1
Name is parallel portzzzz LPT1 Owned status false2
Name is parallel portzzzz LPT2 Owned status false2
```

Comment: Yes, this question is a resubmitted question (100% duplicate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An initial guess would be that the library you use use native code enclosed in a DLL and that code cannot be found giving an error earlier you have missed, and the code falls back to a dummy behaviour.

I would have a closer look at the initialization code to see what happens there.